# Default memory allocation on object creation for ArrayList

Tags: java, memory-management, collections, arraylist

Suppose we are creating an *ArrayList* Object like

```
ArrayList<User> list=new ArrayList<User>();
System.out.println(list.size());   // it will be 0 at this time
```

Now my question is, what memory it will **allocate when this list object will be created in the heap**. I want to know how this memory size is allocated at run time if the size of the list grows dynamically.

Comment: The initial capacity is 10 for an `ArrayList`.  10*(memory size of reference to `User` object) + (overhead) is probably the initial memory allocated

Comment: @CyberneticTwerkGuruOrc Technically, that'd be 10 * (memory size of a reference) + (overhead)

Comment: Ok @CyberneticTwerkGuruOrc , but can you tell me how this works ? i mean how this will be chooses at runtime ??

Comment: @user3580294 Ahh, yes you're right.  Let me edit that

Comment: Quote from the Javadoc(http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html): "Each ArrayList instance has a capacity. The capacity is the size of the array used to store the elements in the list. It is always at least as large as the list size. As elements are added to an ArrayList, its capacity grows automatically. The details of the growth policy are not specified beyond the fact that adding an element has constant amortized time cost."

Comment: Your question is confusing (unclear). The `size()` method does not have anything to do the actual memory allocated by the JVM for your list. You should probably do some reading first http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html, and then come back with some clear question.

Comment: @AshishRatan I would assume that unless you have measured you application in a profiler and determined the size of the ArrayList is too large, I wouldn't worry about it's size.

Comment: @BheshGurung please dude, read my question again... i'm asking about memory allocation size inside heap, size() will be 0 by default if i use it... but my question is different

Comment: `size()` gives no indication of the memory consumed by an `ArrayList` in the heap, as Bhesh stated. The actual memory usage is implementation-specific (unless you specify an initial capacity in the constructor)

Comment: @CyberneticTwerkGuruOrc may i know what is overhead means here ??

Comment: @AshishRatan http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overhead_%28computing%29

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
ArrayList<User> list=new ArrayList<User>();
```

will create an empty `ArrayList`. No objects of User are created or added to the `ArrayList` at this point, and will never be until you explicitly add to it.

`size()` at this point will return `0` as there are no elements in the `ArrayList`.

An ArrayList has a size and has a [capacity](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#ArrayList%28%29). An `ArrayList` is backed by an array. The capacity is the size of the array at a point.

> Each `ArrayList` instance has a `capacity`. The capacity is the size of
>   the array used to store the elements in the list. It is always at
>   least as large as the list size. As elements are added to an
>   ArrayList, its capacity grows automatically. The details of the growth
>   policy are not specified beyond the fact that adding an element has
>   constant amortized time cost.

When an ArrayList is created via the [default constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#ArrayList%28%29), an ArrayList is created with capacity 10.

So technically, the actual memory occupied by the list will be based on the capacity. But note that the array/list is empty. So increass in capacity will have only a marginal impact on the overall size occupied.

You can use a tool like [Java VisualVM](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/visualvm/) (which is included with the JDK) to check the sizes occupied by objects.

Answer (score 1):

**Part 1:** What memory is allocated when the list object is created:

When an ArrayList is created with no default size, the following constructor is called:

```
/**
 * Constructs an empty list with an initial capacity of ten.
 */
public ArrayList() {
    super();
    this.elementData = EMPTY_ELEMENTDATA;
}
```

`super()` here calls an AbstractList constructor which does nothing. `this.elementData` is set to an empty array of objects. Therefore, the memory allocated will be the sum of sizes of the different attributes of the ArrayList class + the 16 bytes allocated to the class itself:

```
public class ArrayList<E> extends AbstractList<E>
    implements List<E>, RandomAccess, Cloneable, java.io.Serializable
{
private static final long serialVersionUID = 8683452581122892189L;

/**
 * Default initial capacity.
 */
private static final int DEFAULT_CAPACITY = 10;

/**
 * Shared empty array instance used for empty instances.
 */
private static final Object[] EMPTY_ELEMENTDATA = {};

/**
 * The array buffer into which the elements of the ArrayList are stored.
 * The capacity of the ArrayList is the length of this array buffer. Any
 * empty ArrayList with elementData == EMPTY_ELEMENTDATA will be expanded to
 * DEFAULT_CAPACITY when the first element is added.
 */
transient Object[] elementData; // non-private to simplify nested class access

/**
 * The size of the ArrayList (the number of elements it contains).
 *
 * @serial
 */
private int size;

 ....
```

You can checkout the [default sizes of primitive data types](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) and do the math to know the exact memory that is used.

But, no memory is used to store any data since an empty `elementData` array is initialized.

**Part 2:**  how this memory size is allocated at run time if the size of the list grows dynamically.

Firstly we see that the ArrayList uses an array `elementData` to keep objects. There is a method that has amortized constant time that I can't exactly remember it's name.

But the idea is that when the array that the ArrayList class uses is filled, the size of the array is doubled. When the ArrayList elements are deleted and only 1/4 of the array is filled, the size of the array is halved.

Answer (score 1):

To answer the 2nd part of your question, yes the allocated memory grows dynamically as you add elements to the ArrayList.  You can estimate the size of an empty ArrayList by looking at the source code.  ArrayList itself just declares three fields:

```
private static final long serialVersionUID = 8683452581122892189L;
private transient Object[] elementData;
private int size;
```

which for an empty list will consume 20 bytes in a 64-bit jvm.  ArrayList extends AbstractList which (including its private classes) declares:

```
int cursor = 0;
int lastRet = -1;
int expectedModCount = modCount;
protected transient int modCount = 0;
private int offset;
private int size;
private int expectedModCount;
```

which adds 28 more bytes, so 48 bytes total.